# How to Build Laravel Production

Tags: laravel

Currently, I'm using Laravel version 6 and I'm new with Laravel never build production before and I would like to encrypt code also because I don't want to someone understand my code after build

Comment: You can encrypt Your code using ioncube, zend. but what You're trying to do is useless work. Your code even if encrypted and deployed to server, it's easy to decrypt op code and reverse the logic if person has access to server. So better take care of server, don't waste Your time. Also it's better to let people also collaborate, since a while after You'll get too much work and will be thinking to delegate Your work to someone else. Also if You do contract work, keep in mind that contracts mostly have sentence where it says that customer is owner of Your code, so You cannot demand on ownership.

Comment: Do not capitalize "You" or "Your". This is not working that way in English and it looks odd.

Comment: thanks for provided good ideas, but I still wondering for example when I build an angular project that angular is the front end I'm using ng build --prod I will get folder dist and inside that folder has the file that already compresses and in laravel we can build like angular or not?